# Why can't I define an vector like this?

Tags: c++, vector

I try to define an vector here. When I use this expression `vector<int> b(1,-1);`, there is a red line under the `1` in the expression and says `Expected ')'`. It is strange because I have a `)` here. When I use another expression `vector<int> a = {-1};`, there is no error.

And when I write the first expression into some function, there is no error, either.

I wonder why the first expression isn't correct.

Thanks!

Here is part of the code:

```
#include "MurmurHash.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>

#ifndef hashMap_h
#define hashMap_h

//using namespace std;

template <typename K, typename V>
class HashTable {
public:
    unsigned long _size;
    unsigned long _elts;
    vector<int> a = {-1};
    vector<int> b(1,-1); // The IDE says Expected ')' here.
    KVPair<K,V> EMPTY = {INT_MIN, a};
    
    HashTable(unsigned long size): _size(2 * size), _elts(0) {
        table = new KVPair<K, V> [_size]();
        fill(table + 0, table + _size, (KVPair<K,V>) EMPTY);
    }
```

Comment: compilers do not add red lines in your code, thats a tool of your ide. Did you try to compile the code? Tools can be wrong. Then please post a [mcve] and the compiler error

Comment: what is `vector<<int>int>` and `vector<i>int>` ?  whats that extra `<int>` and `<i>` ?

Comment: I am sorry that I edit my question in error. it is vector<int>.

Comment: Within a class definition, there are constraints on how you're allowed to initialise members.   `vector<int> b(1,-1)`  - where `b` is a member of a struct or class - is one of the ways not allowed.    If you want such a member, declare `b` without an initialiser in the class definition, and initialise it in a constructor's initialiser list.

Comment: Thanks! But why I initialise **a** here successfully?

Comment: Within a class definition, anything of the form `type name(something)` is treated as a function declaration. You can use curly braces instead.

Comment: You can initialise `a` as you do, because you're using direct initialisation.   Direct initialisation was specifically introduced in C++11, and one of the cases it permits is what you're doing.   Before C++11, initialisation of `a` would also have failed.

Comment: Thank you both! I am so so so grateful!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Point to be noted is that statement `vector<int> b(x)` is used for declaring vector with x length and `vector<int> b{x}` is used for declaring a vector with value x in it.